# Por que preciso do WAMP (exemplo) para que o MySQL funcione?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, wamp

Quando comecei a estudar programação com acesso a banco de dados, precisei instalar softwares como MySQL e o WAMP. Sei do que se trata o WAMP, sei que é um pacote de ferramentas necessárias na hora de programar, porém nunca entendi a importância do dele para o MySQL. Vi que quando eu o desativo não consigo utilizar o banco na minha aplicação feita em Java no NetBeans.

O que é que há nesse pacote que é fundamental para que minha aplicação funcione?

Minha aplicação é um software que serve para armazenar e gerenciar dados de uma determinada empresa.

Comment: O ´MySQL´ não depende do `Wamp Server` ou de outras ferramentas relacionadas. Essas ferramentas simplesmente instalam e "gerenciam" o serviço `MySQL`. Você pode baixar e instalar o `MySQL` manualmente neste link: https://www.mysql.com/
e assim gerenciar o serviço também manualmente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Quando comecei a estudar programação com acesso a banco de dados, precisei instalar softwares como MySQL e o WAMP.

O que está falando não faz muito sentido. O WAMP é Windows Apache MySQL e PHP, portanto ele já tem o MySQL, não tem por que instalá-lo separadamente.

> Sei do que se trata o Wamp, sei que é um pacote de ferramentas necessárias na hora de programar, porém nunca entendi a importância do dele para o MySQL

Não é que precisa para programar, mas ajuda. Ele tem importância zero. Basta você instalar tudo separado. e não precisa dele. Este pacote costuma ser usado por quem não sabe trabalhar com o que se propõe. Ele até pode ser útil para o primeiro contato, porém depois de um tempo se a pessoa continua se valendo dele é porque ainda está fazendo o que não sabe e tem limitações no que produz.

Depois do aprendizado inicial pare de usá-lo.

> Vi que quando eu o desativo não consigo utilizar o banco na minha aplicação feita em java no NetBeans.

Só porque ainda está dependendo dele. Se configurar tudo manualmente não precisa dele. Se está usando Java como linguagem faz bem menos sentido usar o WAMP. Faz sentido ter um servidor web e o banco de dados, mas porque instalar o PHP neste caso?

Acho que aí está adotando a ferramenta errada, principalmente porque disse que já instalou o MySQL. Então não instale o WAMP, instale o Apache. Ou o IIS (na maioria das aplicações não fará muita diferença qual o servidor web está usando (só criará uma pequena dificuldade na hora de publicar).

O mais importante é entender tudo como funciona. Não dá para responder aqui tudo, é necessário vários conhecimentos, precisa a leitura de vários livros, ir acumulando o conhecimento.

> Enfim, minha dúvida é essa: O que é que há nesse pacote WAMP que é fundamental para que minha aplicação funcione?

Nada. Claro que se está usando ele é necessário para rodar sua aplicação.

O Apache é o servidor HTTP que irá receber as requisições do cliente, processá-las e delegar para um executor, no casos é o PHP, o interpretador da linguagem que executará seu código. É comum, mas não garantido que sua aplicação precise de um banco de dados, e é comum que as aplicações PHP usem o MySQL.

Nada disso é necessário para programar. Você pode aprender o oficio do desenvolvimento do jeito certo e entender o papel de cada coisa, tomar decisões próprias, escolher a melhor *stack* de tecnologia que atende sua necessidade, e não ir na onda de mercado. Pode se tornar um profissional com P maiúsculo e fazer a diferença na área.

Se começar pelos fundamentos, entender como as coisas funcionam talvez escolha outras tecnologias para realizar seu trabalho.

Talvez veja que o SQLite é uma escolha melhor para grande dos casos de aplicações web, talvez seja o PostgreSQL ou SQL Server, mesmo no Linux para atender sua necessidade mais complexa.

Pode ser que vá usar tudo no Windows e adote o IIS, ou precise de mais performance e outras características e use o Nginx.

E talvez entenda que PHP é uma facilidade, mas não a melhor linguagem para fazer uma aplicação. Pode ser que queira usar Hack que é como se fosse o PHP, mas escala melhor. Pode ser que vá para Python, ainda uma linguagem de *script que está crescendo no mercado, ou Lua que é mais simples e atende bem a maioria dos casos, até mesmo Ruby poderia ser uma opção. Ou prefira algo que dê mais performance e melhores ferramentas, além de escalar o desenvolvimento melhor como é o caso de Java, C#, Rust, C++, Go, etc.

Pode ser que queira desenvolver direto no Linux se esse for seu alvo de hospedagem. Enfim, poderá adotar o melhor e não o que disseram para você o que fazer. Tenha diferencial de mercado e entenda o que está fazendo. Essa pergunta foi o primeiro passo.

Você pode escolher ser cozinheiro ou chef. O mercado carece de chefs. Não siga receitas de bolo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Para que sua aplicação funcione, você precisa de um servidor de banco de dados esteja funcionando.

Esse servidor de banco de dados pode estar até mesmo em outra máquina desde que acessível pela rede.

Provavelmente quando instalou o "MySql" trata-se de uma aplicação cliente. 
Para não utilizar o Wamp você precisará instalar e configurar o "servidor mysql" manualmente.

Para aprendizado é interessante realizar o processo de instalação do apache, php e mysql manualmente.

Outro tópico interessante para estudo é uso do docker

https://www.docker.com/

https://hub.docker.com/